# Please show code for mathematica

Tags: differential-equations

. Using Mathematica, solve the following differential equation system by completing the following steps:

( + 2) + ( + 1) = 3^−
 + ( + 1) = −3^

a. Use DSolve to solve the system. Use //Simplify to make it simplify as much as possible.
b. Use DSolve to solve the system with the conditions (0) = 0, (0) = 0 and ′(0) = 2.

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. If you have started learning Mathematica, then you will find that the introductory [book](https://www.wolfram.com/language/elementary-introduction/2nd-ed/) written by the inventor is a good learning resource. There is a [fast intro for math students](https://www.wolfram.com/language/fast-introduction-for-math-students/en/) as well as a [fast intro for programmers](https://www.wolfram.com/language/fast-introduction-for-programmers/en/) to choose from.

Comment: `DSolve` cannot solve this system of equations.  Are you sure that it is written correctly?  For instance, should there be a comma after `3 Exp[-t]`?

Comment: @bbgodfrey yes, these should be two ode's on separate lines.  OP wrote them on one line which made it hard at first to read and decode.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the OP has not provided any feedback for an extended period of time.

Answer (score 2):

Next time please show what you tried even if you are new to Mathematica and unable to write the code, any attempt made is better than nothing.

In Mathematica, to solve set of ode's, just write each one on its own, then pass them to `DSolve` as a set. The overall syntax is

```
ode1=...
ode2=...
ic={...}
DSolve[{ ode1, ode2 , ic} , {x[t],y[t]}, t ]
```

The above pattern extends to as many ode's as you have. For 3, it becomes

```
DSolve[{ ode1, ode2 , ode3, ic} , {x[t],y[t], z[t]}, t ]
```

And so on.

For your input the above becomes

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
ode1 = x'[t] + 2*x[t] + y''[t] + y'[t] == 3*Exp[-t]
ode2 = x'[t] + y'[t] + y[t] == -3*Exp[t];
ic = {x[0] == 0, y[0] == 0, y'[0] == 2}
sol1 = DSolve[{ode1, ode2}, {x[t], y[t]}, t]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Simplify[sol1]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

To use IC

```
sol2 = DSolve[{ode1, ode2, ic}, {x[t], y[t]}, t]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

To plot do

```
Plot[{x[t] /. sol2, y[t] /. sol2}, {t, 0, 2}, GridLines -> Automatic, 
 GridLinesStyle -> LightGray, PlotLegends -> {"x(t)", "y(t}"}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]